# PolygonSpriteBatch issues

Tags: libgdx, rendering, polygon, terrain

I have 2 problems with PolygonSpriteBatch on libGDX.

1) I try to render a simple polygon (in this case a rectangle) and I only see a triangle when drawn.

Picture:
http://i.snag.gy/kHV3N.jpg

```
        texture=new TextureRegion(new Texture("texture.png"));
        texture.getTexture().setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
        polygonRegion=new PolygonRegion(texture,createVertices(),createIndices(createVertices()));
```

The polygon that i want to draw is this one

```
 private float[] createVertices() {
   float[] verts = new float[5 * 2];
   int i = 0;
   verts[i++] = 2;
   verts[i++] = 2;
   verts[i++] = 2;
   verts[i++] = 3;
   verts[i++] = 3;
   verts[i++] = 3;
   verts[i++] = 3;
   verts[i++] = 2;
   verts[i++] = verts[0];
   verts[i++] = verts[1];
   return verts;
```

}

```
 private short[] createIndices(float[] vertices){
        short[] indices=new short[vertices.length/2];
        for(short i=0; i<vertices.length/2; i++){
            indices[i]=i;
        }
        return indices;
    }
```

And when I draw it

```
 shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.polygon(createVertices());
    shapeRenderer.end();
    polygonSpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    polygonSpriteBatch.begin();
    polygonSpriteBatch.draw(polygonRegion, 0, 0);

    polygonSpriteBatch.end();
```

I also draw the plain texture to see how it looks like

```
 batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, 4f, 2.4f, 1f, 1f);
    batch.end();
```

As you can see, the polygon is drawn with the shaperenderer correctly, but not well textured with the polygonspritebatch.

The second problem:
Instead of the problem above, polygonspritebatch works perfectly when using a normal camera size, like 800x480.
When I use a camera that is 8 x 4.8 (for box2d world) the texture is zoomed a lot ..like in the picture out there.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue, the problem is the createIndices() function. The third argument to PolygonRegion needs to contain a number of indices that is a multiple of three (the first three vertices form a triangle, etc).

So you should return { 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 }. Also, why do you have 5 vertices? It seems four are enough.

For the second issue, you should clarify your question. From the screenshot, everything seems fine.

Comment: I've changed the way to draw them anyways. Thanks. Mersi.